# How to purge a MSMQ system queue journal programatically?

Tags: .net, msmq, logging

Need to batch a weekly purge of the System queue journal.

Answer (score 5):

The correct format for system queues:

```
FormatName:Direct=os:.\\System$;JOURNAL
```

I've tested this format on Windows 7 and Windows 2003.

(the dot after os: means the localhost/local computer)

```
var systemJournalQueue = new MessageQueue("FormatName:Direct=os:.\\System$;JOURNAL");
var systemDeadLetterQueue = new MessageQueue("FormatName:Direct=os:.\\System$;DEADLETTER");
var systemDeadXLetterQueue =new MessageQueue("FormatName:Direct=os:.\\System$;DEADXACT"));

systemJournalQueue.Purge();
```

or if you want to keep N days of messages you can do this:

```
private static void PurgeQueues(int archiveAfterHowManyDays, MessageQueue queue)
{
    queue.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] { typeof(System.String) });
    queue.MessageReadPropertyFilter.ArrivedTime = true;

    using (MessageEnumerator messageReader = queue.GetMessageEnumerator2())
    {
        int counter = 0;
        while (messageReader.MoveNext())
        {
            Message m = messageReader.Current;
            if (m.ArrivedTime.AddDays(archiveAfterHowManyDays) < DateTime.Now)
            {
                queue.ReceiveById(m.Id);
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
MessageQueue mq = new MessageQueue(".\\Journal$");
mq.Purge();
```

or

```
MessageQueue mq = new MessageQueue(".\\myQueue\\Journal$");
mq.Purge();
```

if its for a queue you created. Make sure the user has the correct permissions. See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[Answerd here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131384/how-to-purge-msmq-system-queue-journal-programaticaly-on-a-workgroup-installation)

```
MessageQueue mq = new MessageQueue("DIRECT=OS:computername\SYSTEM$;JOURNAL");
mq.Purge();
```

Comment: The correct format: 
var mq = new MessageQueue("FormatName:Direct=os:.\\System$;JOURNAL");