# Purge all MSMQ Private Queue Journals

Tags: c#, msmq

I am trying to purge all Journals in all of my private queues.  I am already purging all queues using this code to get the queues:

```
MessageQueue[] queueList = MessageQueue.GetPrivateQueuesByMachine(".");
```

However, there is no method to pull down Journals.  I have tried creating a separate array to store the names but I can't get this back to MessageQueue class.  If I could figure out how to store the names and still be able to use the MessageQueue class against these names, the rest will be easy.

I could also store the names in the app config and pull them from here but again, I do not know how to link this back to the MessageQueue class.

If anyone has an idea let me know.

Thanks

Comment: I got this working.  I will post the code when I get a chance if anyone is interested.

Comment: Used this:

[MSMQ : How to purge system queue journal programaticaly?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063378/msmq-how-to-purge-system-queue-journal-programaticaly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this link and used the PurgeQueues.

[MSMQ : How to purge system queue journal programaticaly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063378/msmq-how-to-purge-system-queue-journal-programaticaly)

I kept the same code I was using to get the Queues, just added this code to do the clearing.